# CSS3 Animation very laggy in firefox only

Tags: css, animation, firefox

We have made a very nice animation, which you can find here: http://marcel60.ch/old

In all major browsers (chrome, IE, Edge, Safari) the whole animation is very smooth and just awesome. However, in firefox it's horribly laggy.

What is firefox doing there? Is there a way to improve the performance?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I see that, but there is no minimal way to reproduce it. The point is exactly, that many animations are played synchronously and firefox seems not to be able to handle it. All other browsers do.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. Add one layer at a time and see how performance degrades, so you may at least know if the issue is dependant on the amount of layers or just one specific layer

Comment: It's also lagging very hard in Opera. And you are not really using CSS Animations, you are manipulating positions of pixels for each element via Javascript. No wonder this has bad performance. You should use real CSS animations.